# How to add in NativeBase footer in my react native app?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am newbie in React Native. I would like to add in footer bar in my App. 
Here is my full code in dashboard.js file but it does not work:-

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import Background from '../components/Background';
import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import Paragraph from '../components/Paragraph';
import Button from '../components/Button';

import {Container, Footer, Title, Icon} from 'native-base';


const Dashboard = ({ navigation }) => (
  <Background>
    <Logo />
    <Header>Let’s start</Header>
    <Paragraph>
      Your amazing app starts here. Open you favourite code editor and start
      editing this project.
    </Paragraph>
    <Button mode="outlined" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')}>
      Logout
    </Button>

    **<Container>
                <Footer>
                    <Button transparent>
                        <Icon size={30} color={'#fff'} name={'ios-telephone'} />
                    </Button>
                    <Title>Footer</Title>
                    <Button transparent >
                        <Icon size={25} color={'#fff'} name={'chatbox'}/>
                    </Button>
                </Footer>
            </Container>**
  </Background>

);

export default memo(Dashboard);
```

The error show that the fontfamily issue caused in native-base.

[image]

Therefore, I did some research and getting this solution.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      ...Ionicons.font,
    });
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }
```

But I have no idea how to add this in my code, anyone can help for this? Appreciated.

Comment: shall i change your code into  a class component rather than functional component? ill then show you how to do it

Comment: @GauravRoy Currently I got a login page and will redirect to this page (Dashboard.js) after logged in. You changes will impact this after change to class component? You may show me your solution and I will try for it... Thousand appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to keep an initial state as false until data is loaded

```
state = {
    isReady: false
  }
```

Then inside componentDidMount you can load data & when the data is loaded change state.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        Roboto: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
        Roboto_medium: require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
        ...Ionicons.font,
      });
      this.setState({ isReady: true })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error loading fonts', error);
    }
  }
```

Finally render your data

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        {
          this.state.isReady ?
            <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto', fontSize: 56 }}>Hello, world!</Text>
            :
            <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
              <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
```

You can apply the same scenario for functional component, But use useEffect() instead of componentDidMount()

Comment: Hi @SDushan, I saw this solution as well but I have no idea how to embedded in this code ```const Dashboard = ({ navigation }) => ( ```